# Angularjs + Angular (5) router

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-ui-router, angular-router

I am trying to run **angular** next to our old **angularjs** application. Before we try to go the **ngUpgrade** (a lot of refactoring needed before possible) route I'd like to try and run them independent from each other. I thought I would be able to achieve this by just rendering the  tag and the associated script files that get generated (by angular-cli) on the specified routes that I want to upgrade to our new application.

I do this by adding a state to my **angular-ui-router**. With *param as last url value so all subsequent routes go to the same route.
[img-link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYkOj.png)

But now I have an issue that when I redirect from an **angularjs**`(e.g. /user)` route to a new route( e.g. /subscription/2) the application breaks because angular can't resolve the previous route.

I thought this could work if I could intercept the **routeChange** in angular but can't find a way to do this.

Is this even possible?

Comment: I'm not sure if I properly understand what it means to be running the applications side by side; can you provide a more in depth explanation and/or code sample?

Answer (score -1):

In order for angular to intercept and handle routes you need to use an UrlHandlingStrategy. Please check the example [here](http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/ngupgrade-with-the-angular-router-and-ui-router).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, link only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow, you can improve this answer by taking vital parts of the link and putting it into your answer, this makes sure your answer is still an answer if the link gets changed or removed :)

Comment: link is not accessible

Comment: Thanks for the link chalapenioz.. keep going +1